# Git: Not seeing commits with "git log" in local repo after having "git fetch"ed

Tags: git

My Bitbucket remote has these latest commits:

```
Commit  Message     Commit date
d9578f5f628 Version ***NO_CI***     3 days ago  
3f3aebefcd0 Added files for git build       3 days ago  
dab48971291 Version 22.1.0.0113 ***NO_CI***     6 days ago  
8b63be0cb15 Version 22.1.0.0112 ***NO_CI***     6 days ago
```

(copied from the web interface commit log)

Locally, I cannot see the latest 2 commits:

```
> git log --all --oneline -5
5cc97e6108 (HEAD -> default) Version 22.1.0.0114 ***NO_CI***
dab4897129 (origin/default, origin/HEAD) Version 22.1.0.0113 ***NO_CI***
8b63be0cb1 Version 22.1.0.0112 ***NO_CI***
396e33eab1 Version 22.1.0.0111 ***NO_CI***
af86c6a0d9 Version 22.1.0.0110 ***NO_CI***
```

Even though I successfully (?) fetched before:

```
> git fetch ssh://[url masked]
From ssh://[url masked]
 * branch                  HEAD       -> FETCH_HEAD
```

What am I missing?
I might have done some bad things with git reset earlier. Not an experienced gitter.

PS: I don't want to update my working copy. Just check what latest commits are in the repo.

Comment: You fetch by the remote name, not by the url. `git fetch some-remote-name` (like `git fetch origin`).

Comment: This may help, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070496/having-a-hard-time-understanding-git-fetch. `git fetch <url>` is not for daily use, and it needs more parameters to do what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

When using `git fetch` this way (with a raw URL instead of a remote name), you must change a lot of things about how you use Git, as [ElpieKay noted in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73811911/git-not-seeing-commits-with-git-log-in-local-repo-after-having-git-fetched#comment130334861_738119110) that links to [Having a hard time understanding git-fetch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1070496/1256452).  In particular, after this `git fetch`, you would need to use `git log FETCH_HEAD`.  The `--all` flag to `git log` means *all refs*, but `FETCH_HEAD` is peculiar:

- it's sometimes a "pseudo-ref" (as are the other non-`HEAD` `*_HEAD` entities);
- it's never included by `--all` here.

Other pseudo-refs will hold a single commit hash ID, but `FETCH_HEAD` often holds multiple lines, with each line holding a hash ID.  In these cases it must be hand-parsed.  As your particular `git fetch` output showed only one line, you won't be hitting this particular case at this particular time, but keep it in mind.